# C++ DLL Injection: path with special characters

Tags: c++, qt, dll, code-injection

I'm trying to solve this situation.
I have win32 program, that waiting until specific process is started "Example.exe", then the program inject "my.dll" into process "Example.exe"

It works fine until the user have program under folder with specific, but allowed characters, for example in my country default folder name is "Nová složka" (New folder)

I tried to use relative path

```
"//my.dll"
"/my.dll"
"\\my.dll"
"\my.dll"
```

unsuccessfully... Also I tried different ways to convert string(QString) to char array.

Developed in Qt 5.1.1

**Here is code where the program finding path of .dll**

```
QString actualPath(QDir::currentPath() + "/my.dll");
ui->lblDebug->setText(actualPath);
const char* myChar = QString(actualPath.toUtf8()).toStdString().c_str();
QString q = QString::fromStdString(myChar);
ui->lblDebug->setText(q);
```

**Here is the injection part**

```
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PE32.th32ProcessID);
hModule = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 512, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, hModule, (LPVOID)myChar, 512, NULL);
CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA"), hModule, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
qDebug() << "INJECT:DONE!";
return true; ExitProcess(0);
break;
```

**Do you have any ideas, How to pass to the function WriteProcessMemory right path with correct characters? Thanks.**

Comment: What's the error message? It might be a character encoding issue.

Comment: There is no error message, It compile the program with no errors, it also work fine with path like "C:\my.dll" or "D:\Program Files\My files\my.dll" but not with "C:\Nová složka\my.dll"

Comment: @AdamKennyŠmíd: That doesn't address what Drew MgGowen's stated. Just because code compiles only means that the code is syntactically correct. It doesn't mean it will run correctly.  Forget about WriteProcessMemory for a moment.  Can you write a simple Windows program that can access that directory?  Maybe start with that, as this does look like an encoding issue.

Comment: For example, can you get this sample program to determine if the path exists? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx If not, then the issue is encoding. Either a code page issue, or you need to escape the string properly to address those foreign characters.

Comment: Now my program is quite large, I have many functions that are working with files, folders, uploading them to FTP. It works pretty nice if I use Qt functions, but for the injection I have to use windows function. Project\Editor\Files is saved under UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You're using the ANSI version of `LoadLibrary`. You should then be using the local 8 bit encoding, *not* UTF-8. The gyrations that you go through to get the ANSI version of the path are unnecessary. You also shouldn't be using a fixed buffer size.

```
QString const actualPath(QDir::currentPath() + "/my.dll");
// This byte array must exist until the `WriteProcessMemory` call.
QByteArray const path = actualPath.toLocal8Bit();
int const bufLen = path.size() + 1;

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PE32.th32ProcessID);
hModule = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, bufLen, 
                         MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, hModule, (LPVOID)path.constData(), bufLen, NULL);
CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
  GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA"),
  hModule, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

What you should really be doing, though, is using the UCS-2 encoding with `LoadLibraryW`:

```
QString const path(QDir::currentPath() + "/my.dll");
int const bufLen = (path.length()+1) * 2;

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PE32.th32ProcessID);
hModule = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, bufLen,
                         MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, hModule, (LPVOID)path.constData(), bufLen, NULL);
CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
  GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW"),
  hModule, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```